# Use compareTo Method with LinkedList to Add Objects Alphabetically

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

I have created my own LinkedList which contains a Song object(title, artist etc..). I am trying to add a function where the user enters song details and it adds the song to the list alphabetically by ARTIST. My issue is that i am not sure how to set up the if else statements to add it to the list alphabetically by artist, thanks in advance.

**compareTo() in Song Class**

```
//Should return negative if in order, positive if out of order, 0 if equal
public int compareTo(Song s) {
        return title.compareTo(s.getTitle()); //I think this is correct?
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void addSong(LinkedList list){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter song title: ");
    String title = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter song artist: ");
    String artist = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter song album: ");
    String album = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter song length: ");
    String length = input.nextLine();

    Song songInfo = new Song(title, artist, album, length);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
        if ( //compareTo should be used here < 0 ){
        }else if( //compareTo should be used here == 0)

    }
```

**LinkedList Class Add Method**

```
public class LinkedList {
private Node first;
private Node last;
public LinkedList(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
}
public void add( Song c ){
    if( isEmpty() ) {
        first = new Node(c);
        last = first;
    }else{
        Node n = new Node(c);
        last.setNext(n);
        last = n;
    }
}
```

**Node Class**

```
public class Node {
private Song song;
private Node next;
public Node( Song s ){
    song = s;
    next = null;
}
public Node( Song s, Node n ){
    song = s;
    next = n;
}
public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}
public void setNext(Node n){
    next = n;
}
public Song getValue(){
    return song;
}
public void setValue( Song s ){
    song = s;
}
```

Comment: Just walk the list until you find the first element _greater_ than yours. Then add in your element _before_ that one. So you need to `implements Iterable<Song>` and then your need to implement an `Iterator` that supports `add` in the middle of your `List`.

Comment: Modify your `add` logic to find the appropriate index where to insert `Node` instead of adding at last always. see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ok, I am a bit confused still. I am not sure if the if statement should look somethinglike this or is this completely off if (artist.compareTo(list.get(i).getValue().getArtist()) < 0 )

Comment: **You should never `get(i)` from a `LinkedList**; hint: looping over the `List` and calling `get(i)` for each element - what's the time complexity of that? So you need to `implements Iterable` and see where that takes you.